# How to Overload operator[] for a Two-Dimmensional Array in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I have a class **Map** that uses a `vector<Cell>` to store a two dimensional array of `Cell`s. I overloaded `operator[]` to access the data inside **Map** using `map[i][j]`.

My problem is that it only works for the first row of data. As soon as `i = 1` I get a Segmentation Fault. The code is below, any help will be greatly appreciated! **Thank you**.

**Inside the Map class** (If you need more details let me know):

```
/* Declaration of the vector<Cell> */
vector<Cell> map_;

/* The Operator Overload */
const Cell* operator[](int x) const {
    return &map_[x * this->width_];
}

/* Constructor */
explicit Map(double mapStep) : stepSize_(trunc(mapStep * 1000) / 1000) {
    if (mapStep > 0) {
        this->height_ = trunc((ARENA_HEIGHT / mapStep));
        this->width_ = trunc((ARENA_WIDTH / mapStep));
    } else { cerr << "Map Constructor Error #2" << endl; return; }

    mapInit();
}

void mapInit() {
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    this->map_.resize(this->height_ * this->width_);

    for (auto &cell : this->map_) {
        cell = Cell(Cell::cell_type::NOGO, i, j);
        if (j < this->width_ - 1) { j++; } else { j = 0; i++; }
    }
}
```

**The code in `main()`:**

```
int i = 0, j = 0;
Map * map = new Map(20);

for (; i < map->getHeight() ;) {
    cout << "[" << map[i][j]->x << ", " << map[i][j]->y << ", " << map[i][j]->t << "]";

    if (j < map->getWidth() - 1) { j++; } else { j = 0; i++; cout << endl; }
}
```

**The Output**

```
[0, 0, 255][1, 0, 255][2, 0, 255][3, 0, 255][4, 0, 255][5, 0, 255][6, 0, 255][7, 0, 255][8, 0, 255][9, 0, 255][10, 0, 255][11, 0, 255]
Segmentation fault
```

The first line of output seems to be correct, and previous tests using an overload of `operator()` worked fine, I just really need to use [ ] instead.

Comment: Having a one dimensional vector of cells and utilizing the operator () (size_t row, size_t column) would make it an easy 'row * number_of_colums + column' calculation

Comment: Check [C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-subscript-op) and another [section](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-array-of-array), too!

Comment: @DieterLücking You are right, and that was my initial approach. I just need to understand why this is not working. If I can't find an answer I will probably have to use () instead. Thanks!

Comment: @Aerozeek We don't know how you constructed the map (this code: `Map * map = new Map(20);`).  Also, there is no need in your `main` function for `new Map(20);` -- just this: `Map map(20);`

Comment: @Naszta Great link, thank you. I understand the advantages and simplicity of () over [] in this case, but the essence of the question is **why my code doesn't work**. Thanks!

Comment: @Aerozeek To answer **why**, we need to see your Map constructor.   Otherwise it is guessing.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I updated the code to include the line that actually creates the map. Thanks!

Comment: @Aerozeek No.  Please post your actual constructor, not a line or two plucked out of your program.  We need the *full* context of that line in `main`.  Expected is this: `Map::Map(int num) { ... }`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Done, but you'll see why I didn't do it before --the rest of it is hardly relevant. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know **why** it was failing, but I was able to fix it by following Paul's suggestion to replace `Map * map = new Map(20);` with `Map map(20);`

My Java background is probably obvious now.
Thank you all!

Comment: you could also replace `map[i][j]` with `(*map)[i][j]` instead.

Comment: @Wimmel Thanks, good to know. The reason why I need this object to be as similar as a Java array as possible, is because the developers that will use the class are novices in C++ like myself.